# Making an advertising server ads from different ad networks

Tags: advertising, google-dfp, ad-server

In India there are many ad-networks(other than Adsense) who pay per acquisition or per lead. So Javascript ad code is not required(as fraud clicks don't matter as long as one converts).

So an ad network will have many companies and each company will have many banner sizes for ads. Also suddenly any ad may be stopped just because company's target has met. Which is a common nuisance since if we don't remove those url's then that company will get conversions for free.

I've a dozen sites and removing the ads are difficult every now and then. Also CPA based ads may not convert at all. That means I'll need to remove non-performing ads regularly.

I've gone through: [How can I show multiple ad networks on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2825/how-can-i-show-multiple-ad-networks-on-my-site) . I've also visited DFP solution but without Adsense they wouldn't let me open account.

I want to make an ad server wherein I'll feed new ads (banner image + link for click). I want to maintain categories there like ( shoes, phones, books etc). So if an ad is paused - i'll simply remove/pause the ad there while other ads in the category keep running. Also changing ad code within sites will no more be required.

For example - let me have an ad category "clothing" where I can add ads from different companies. So if one of my site requests an ad from there it'll randomly select an ad in this category and return it to site for display. Removing/adding ads within this category will not affect the site requesting those ads.

Any idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at OpenX. The standard free edition should suffice for what you are trying to achieve. Basically OpenX is your own hosted Ad Server, which allows you to set up your own logic on when, how often and what types of ads will be delivered. You simply ad your ad codes to the server (instead of creating your own creatives) and let the system handle delivery of your ad networks.

**For example:**

- Ad#1: Javascript code to display Banner Ads in 300x250px from Ad
  Network 1
- Ad#2: Javascript code to display Banner Ads in 300x250px
  from Ad Network 2
- Ad#3: Javascript code to display Banner Ads in
  300x250px from Ad Network 3
- Ad#4: Javascript code to display Banner
  Ads in 160x600px from Ad Network 1
- Ad#5: Javascript code to display
  Banner Ads in 160x600px from Ad Network 2
- Ad#6: Javascript code to
  display Banner Ads in 160x600px from Ad Network 3

Now, you only have to add two "Zones" to OpenX. One zone for 300x250px and one zone for 160x600px. These "zones" gives you javascript codes which you implement on your website. The OpenX server now looks up valid ads for these zones and display either Ad#1, Ad#2 or Ad#3 for Zone 1 and Ad#4, Ad#5 and Ad#6 for Zone 2.

If you pause or delete an ad, that ad will of course not be delivered anymore to your specified zone.

**Links and information:**

http://www.openx.com/publisher/open-source-ad-server

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenX_(software)

Answer (score 0):

OpenX is just one of the hundred alternatives. It's the oldest ones, but I wouldn't say the best one. You can take a look at Epom, Adzerk, Smartadserver. They work exactly the same way, the difference is in the pricing and features.